# react initial state calculated from DOM

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I am using https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-slick and I'm trying to make it est "slidesToShow" dynamically based on available width.

I've managed to get it working, but only after window resize. I need to supply it with an initial state calculated from an element width. The problem is that the element doesn't exist at that point.

This is my code (the interesting parts):

```
const Carousel = (props: ICarouselProps) => {
  const slider = useRef(null);
  const recalculateItemsShown = () => {
    const maxItems = Math.round(
      slider.current.innerSlider.list.parentElement.clientWidth / 136, // content width is just hardcoded for now.
    );
    updateSettings({...props.settings, slidesToShow: maxItems});
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('resize', recalculateItemsShown);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('resize', recalculateItemsShown);
    };
  });

  const [settings, updateSettings] = useState({
    ...props.settings,
    slidesToShow: //How do I set this properly? slider is null here
  });

  return (
    <div id="carousel" className="carousel">
      <Slider {...settings} {...arrows} ref={slider}>
        <div className="test-content/>
        <div className="test-content/>
        /* etc. */
        <div className="test-content/>
        <div className="test-content/>
        <div className="test-content/>
      </Slider>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Carousel;
```

if I call `updateSettings` in my `useEffect` I get an infinite loop.

So I would have to either:

- Somehow get the width of an element that hasn't yet been created
- or
- call updateSettings once after the very first render.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have a function that returns `maxItems` and use that everywhere, so:

```
const getMaxItems = () => Math.round(slider.current.innerSlider.list.parentElement.clientWidth / 136)
```

You use its return result within `recalculateItemsShown` to update the settings.

```
const recalculateItemsShown = () => {
  updateSettings({...props.settings, slidesToShow: getMaxItems()});
};
```

And you also use its return value to set the state initially.

```
const [settings, updateSettings] = useState({
  ...props.settings,
  slidesToShow: getMaxItems()
});
```

If the element doesn't exist initially, you could use `useEffect` with an empty array as the second argument. This tells `useEffect` to watch changes to that array and call it everytime it changes, but since its an empty array that never changes, it will only run once - on initial render.

```
useEffect(() => {
  updateSettings({...props.settings, slidesToShow: getMaxItems()});
}, []);
```

You can read more about skipping applying events here: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-optimizing-performance-by-skipping-effects

Comment: `Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops` Can't call updateSettings from useEffect =/

Comment: ah my bad, if you want to run useEffect only once after initial render, give it `[]` as second argument. I'll update the post in a sec with why this happens.

Comment: Done, it should work as expected now. @JohanHjalmarsson

Answer (score 1):

I believe the `uselayouteffect` hook is designed for this exact use case.

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#uselayouteffect

It works exactly the same way as useEffect except that it fires after the dom loads so that you can calculate the element width as needed.

Comment: `Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.` Made no difference since I still can't call `setState`

Comment: Same as the response above, you have to pass an empty array as the second parameter to an effect hook if you just want it to load once on mount. This is a different question though, now you're just asking how to use the useEffects hook api.

Comment: If you want to be able to refer to `slider.current.innerSlider.list.parentElement.clientWidth` you can do so by using the layout hook, which works like the effect hook but will run after the paint, so the slider element will exist in the dom at that point and can be referred to. Perhaps I have misunderstood the problem. Is that not what you were after?

Comment: Your initial response on this thread is confusing because you mention `setState` but there is no `setState` method when dealing with hooks. If you want to deal with component state in a stateless functional component you're going to have to use a `useState` hook, and to set the state you can refer to the useState setter inside the `uselayouteffect`. This is the answer to a completely different question though.

Comment: I've managed to get it to work now thanks to your and Dragos' answers, Thanks alot =)